# How can I fix directory detection in GWT's nocache.js?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

My GWT/forplay project has stopped working.  The project/project.nocache.js file makes the browser request md5hash.cache.html, rather than project/md5hash.cache.html.  (It tries to load from one directory too high.)  This results in a 404, of course.  I have seen this across browsers, and even across servers.

Can anybody with nocache.js knowledge take a guess at why it now fails to point the browser to the right place for the cache.html file?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of GWT? do you load the nocache.js file the "standard" way? What changed between "it worked" and "it no longer works"?

Comment: +1 to @ThomasBroyer. Too few information.
What is in your index.html file? What is in your *.gwt.xml file(s)?